# maps:put(Key,Value,Map) not working in erlang

Tags: erlang

`maps:put(key,value,Map)` not working

```
Map = #{"a" => 1},
maps:put("a", 42, Map),
maps:put("b", 1337, Map),
io:fwrite("~p~n",[Map]).
```

output #

```
{"a" => 1}
```

Why I am not able to get output #`{"a" => 42,"b" => 1337}`?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ all the objects in [tag:erlang] are immutable. One cannot expect to modify _any_ object. Once created, it stays forever.

Answer (score 5):

The [`maps:put/3` function](https://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#put-3) returns a new map. You can see that it doesn't alter `Map` if you look at the variable again after the first `maps:put/3` call:

```
1> Map = #{"a" => 1}.
#{"a" => 1}.
2> maps:put("a", 42, Map).
#{"a" => 42}
3> Map.
#{"a" => 1}
```

As you can see, `Map` retains its initial value.

To fix the problem, you need to capture the `maps:put/3` return value into a new variable:

```
4> Map1 = maps:put("a", 42, Map).
#{"a" => 42}
5> Map2 = maps:put("b", 1337, Map1).
#{"a" => 42,"b" => 1337}
```

Now the variable `Map2` has the value you're looking for.